# Scripting Creation Of Database Diagrams

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-diagrams

Is it possible to script the creation of a database diagram using T-SQL?

If not, what is the Database Diagram Designer doing when you use it to save / edit a diagram (is it using PowerShell or some other language to save and load these type of objects)?

I ask because I'm looking to automate the creation of database diagrams.
I have a tool one of my developers wrote (in C#) which automatically creates tables and their foreign key relationships based on the responses of some web service calls it makes to our vendors' data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Database Diagram objects are indeed created using T-SQL.  You can see what SSMS does when creating, editing, and saving diagrams by running a T-SQL trace against your development SQL Server while using the Database Diagram tools.

A database that has the Database Diagram objects enabled will contain a `dbo.sysdiagrams` table.

Many properties use by the Database Diagram system are stored in Extended Properties.  These can be seen looking at `sys.extended_properties` in the diagram-enabled database.

The following objects are also engaged in the Database Diagram system:

```
dbo.sp_upgraddiagrams
dbo.sysdiagrams
dbo.sp_helpdiagrams
dbo.sp_helpdiagramdefinition
dbo.sp_creatediagram
dbo.sp_renamediagram
dbo.sp_alterdiagram
dbo.sp_dropdiagram
```

Hopefully the above details will get you on the road to reverse-engineering the Database Diagram system, however be aware the actual diagrams are stored in a binary format that is, as far as I can tell, [not documented](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%22database+diagram%22+binary+format+site%3Amicrosoft.com+%22sql+server%22&t=ffsb&atb=v65-7&ia=web).